Equivariant Multiplicative Formula for Sphere Bundles in the Index Theorem
I am reading through the proof of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem, out of Lawson-Michelson, and I'm a bit confused about the proof of multiplicative property for indices of sphere bundles, where I feel the construction of the necessary differential operator does not line up with the construction of the multiplication map on bundles.
Given a principal $O_n$-bundle $\mathbf{P}$ over a compact manifold $X$, setting $Z = \mathbf{P} \times_{O_n} S^n$, LM defines a multiplicative map $K_{\text{cpt}}(T^* X) \otimes K_{O_n, \text{cpt}}(T^*S^n) \to K_{\text{cpt}}(T^*Z)$ as follows:

Given $v \in K_{O_n, \text{cpt}}(T^* S^n)$, let $\pi \colon \mathbf{P} \times T^* S^n \to T^* S^n$ be the projection. Then pull $v$ back to $\mathbf{P} \times T^* S^n$, yielding an element of $K_{O_n, \text{cpt}}(\mathbf{P} \times T^* S^n)$. Now quotient by the $O_n$ action on $\pi^* v \to \mathbf{P} \times T^* S^n$ to get an element of $K_{\text{cpt}}(\mathbf{P} \times_{O_n} T^*S^n)$.
Identifying $\mathbf{P} \times_{O_n} T^* S^n$ with $T^* Z/p^* T^* X$, we can take the product $T^* X \times T^*Z/p^* T^* X$, a bundle over $X \times X$. Then given $u \in K_{\text{cpt}}(T^* X)$, take the outer tensor product of $u$ and the image of $v$ under the process above, and restrict the resulting bundle to the diagonal. This yields an element of $K_{\text{cpt}}(T^* Z)$.

This is all well and good. The goal is then to prove that $\text{ind}(u \cdot v) = \text{ind}(u \cdot \text{ind}_{O_n} v)$. To do so we take first order operators $P$ and $Q$ representing $u$ and $v$, with $Q$ being $O_n$-equivariant, and construct a new differential operator out of the two, whose symbol is $u \cdot v$. Then we compute the index of the resulting operator and prove that it equals the RHS of the above equation.
My confusion stems from the construction of the operator for $u \cdot v$. LM says that we should take a trivializing cover of $\mathbf{P}$, lift $P$ to each trivial set, and then glue using a partition of unity to get an $O_n$-invariant operator on $\mathbf{P}$. Then we take the outer tensor product of this new operator with $Q$, to obtain an operator whose symbol is "easily checked" to represent the class $u \cdot v$.
However, here we are taking an operator on $T^* X$ bundle, extending it to something $O_n$-equivariant on all of $\mathbf{P}$, and then quotienting its outer tensor tensor product with another $O_n$-equivariant operator to pass from $\mathbf{P} \times S^n$ to $\mathbf{P} \times_{O_n} S^n = Z$. This seems distinct from the process of constructing $u \cdot v$, where we instead extended the object living over $T^* S^n$ and took the outer tensor product of that with the original class $u \in K_{\text{cpt}}(T^* X)$.
Why does this operator represent the correct bundle, and more generally, why should one choose to construct $u \cdot v$ and the operator living on it using these two different procedures?

After a few days of thinking I realized the issue was actually that my observation that we are only extending $u$ and not $v$ was not correct: given our operators $P$ and $Q$, we must extend both to operators representing difference elements in $K_{\text{cpt}}(p^* T^* X)$ and $K_{\text{cpt}}(\mathbf{P} \times_{O_n} T^* S^n)$. Both spaces in here themselves are bundles over the quotient $\mathbf{P} \times_{O_n} S^n$. But while $Q$ is equivariant from the start, $P$ is not, so constructing the correct operator requires slightly more core. I will leave the rest of the details here in case anyone else has a similar issue. Also I will note that reading Atiyah and Singer's original paper, The Index of Elliptic Operators: I, was very helpful for clarifying this and some other questions I had about the treatment of the proof in Lawson-Michelson.
More specifically, to construct the difference element on $T^* Z$, you of course need to pull each bundle in the difference element $u \in K_\text{cpt}(T^* X)$ back to a bundle over $p^* T^* X$. So to construct the associated operator, you can choose to start off with a non-equivariant operator $P$ between bundles over $X$, turn it into an equivariant operator on the pullback of $T^* X$ over $\mathbf{P} \times T^* S^n$, and then pass to the quotient, which is an operator between bundles over $p^* T^*X$, itself lying over $Z$.
Likewise you must turn the equivariant operator $Q$ between $O_n$-bundles over $S^n$ into an operator representing an element in $K_\text{cpt}(\mathbf{P} \times_{O_n} T^* S^n)$. But in this case your operator is already equivariant so it is easy to go directly to the quotient.
The symbols of both operators are given by extending the symbols of $P$ and $Q$ along the "vertical" and "horizontal" fibers in the obvious way ($\sigma(\tilde{P})(\xi, \eta) = \sigma(P)(\xi)$ and $(\sigma(\tilde{Q})(\xi, \eta) = \sigma(\tilde{Q})(\eta)$. So when we take the outer tensor product, the symbol we get is clearly going to be the outer tensor product of $u$ and $v$ after pulling them back to bundles over $Z$.
